# snmp: getting the short interface name instead of long ifDescr (again)

Tags: debian, snmp, debian-wheezy, debian-jessie

I'm using [cricket](http://cricket.sourceforge.net/) to do some simple monitoring (including network devices) of my Debian-based servers.

The interfaces are identified by name (e.g. `eth0`, `eth1`,...), and cricket maps these names to the proper OIDs by looking them up in `IF-MIB::ifDescr`:

```
$ snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 1 wheezy 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1 = STRING: "lo"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2 = STRING: "eth0"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.3 = STRING: "eth1"
```

Everything worked cool until I upgraded my machine to Debian/jessie today.
Now the reported interface names are a long description of the brand:

```
$ snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 1 jessie 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1 = STRING: "lo"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2 = STRING: "Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.3 = STRING: "Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection"
```

While I find the long name annoying enough, it becomes useless as it is no longer unique: since the machine in question has two identical network cards built in, I just get the same name twice.

Is there a way to make `snmpd` report the *short* interface names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that using `IF-MIB::ifDescr` for the interface *name* is simply wrong.
As the name of the OID implies, this is meant to be a (verbose) description ofthe interface, rather than a (unique) name.

The proper OID to use is `IF-MIB::ifName`

```
$ snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 1 wheezy 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.1 = STRING: "lo"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.2 = STRING: "eth0"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.3 = STRING: "eth1"

$ snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 1 jessie 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.1 = STRING: "lo"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.2 = STRING: "eth0"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.3 = STRING: "eth1"
```

In the case of `cricket` this means that i changed the cricket-configuration of the interface-map to:

```
OID    ifName                 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1 

map interface-name
    base-oid    =   ifName
    match       =   %interface-name%
```